# Can postNotificationName be used to call a previous view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to have a "Cancel" button send the user to the previous view in my iPhone app. Can postNotificationName be used to do this? How can I define the previous view?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for -[NSNotification postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]. this allows you to add objects (such as the view to display, or a string identifier for it) to the notification messages.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Do you, by any chance, know how to call a "previous view" object or define it in some way?

Comment: something like `-[UIViewController viewWillDisappear:]` should do the trick